# How do I use the Convincing persona feat without dual identity or masked persona

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

> People seem almost willfully ignorant of the connection between your
>   masked persona and your real identity. Prerequisite(s): Bluff 5 ranks,
>   Perform (act) 5 ranks, or dual identity class feature. Benefit(s):
>   Your dual identity is never considered publicly compromised barring
>   some massive, public unmasking, allowing you to benefit from your dual
>   identity or masked persona regardless of how many people know your
>   true identity. You gain a +5 circumstance bonus on Bluff skill checks
>   to convince people your masked persona and your true identity are
>   entirely different people, and on Disguise checks to maintain your
>   masked persona.

The feat reads as such, from that I can’t see anything that can be gained from the ability without that class feature. Am I wrong on that. Maybe the “or” is a typo and they meant “and” instead?

I took it by mistake on a previous character not realizing it went with a class feature. Then again that character was an optimization nightmare and I ended up just rerolling first chance I got. So doesn’t really matter now. I might make a vigilante some day once I get over my obsession with casters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feat [**Convincing Persona**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/convincing-persona/) is useful not *only* to those who possess the extraordinary ability [**dual identity**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Vigilante/#Dual_Identity_Ex) (a level 1 vigilante class feature) but also to those who've undergone the ritual of creating a [**masked persona**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/masked-personas/), an "option available to all classes."

However, the Convincing Persona feat *is* pretty much useless if a creature doesn't possess the extraordinary ability dual identity *and* hasn't undergone the masked persona ritual, but *Pathfinder* has many feats like this. (For example, the feat [Quicken Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic/) can be taken by a creature that can't cast spells.)

A creature that meets the Convincing Persona feat's prerequisites yet possesses neither a dual identity nor a masked persona may take the feat in anticipation of realizing its benefit later, for example.